# How to apply Fabric UI Office theme to body background?

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, web, themes, office-ui-fabric

I've got a problem with theming a react website made with fabric ui

I've generated 2 themes (Night/Day mode) using the website that Fabric UI provided for generating themes. I exported them in json format.
As i want to use a toggle button to change between these two themes, those two jsons became variables in a file "Themes.json"

Problem is that, once i change the theme, the body's background which is supposed to be dark is in fact plain white

My themes

```
var lightCyan = {
    "themePrimary": "#009486",
    "themeLighterAlt": "#f1fbfa",
    "themeLighter": "#c8eeea",
    "themeLight": "#9cdfd8",
    "themeTertiary": "#4cbfb4",
    "themeSecondary": "#13a193",
    "themeDarkAlt": "#008578",
    "themeDark": "#007166",
    "themeDarker": "#00534b",
    "neutralLighterAlt": "#f8f8f8",
    "neutralLighter": "#f4f4f4",
    "neutralLight": "#eaeaea",
    "neutralQuaternaryAlt": "#dadada",
    "neutralQuaternary": "#d0d0d0",
    "neutralTertiaryAlt": "#c8c8c8",
    "neutralTertiary": "#595959",
    "neutralSecondary": "#373737",
    "neutralPrimaryAlt": "#2f2f2f",
    "neutralPrimary": "#000000",
    "neutralDark": "#151515",
    "black": "#0b0b0b",
    "white": "#ffffff"
}

var darkCyan = {
    "themePrimary": "#4fedec",
    "themeLighterAlt": "#030909",
    "themeLighter": "#0d2626",
    "themeLight": "#184747",
    "themeTertiary": "#2f8e8e",
    "themeSecondary": "#45d1d0",
    "themeDarkAlt": "#5fefee",
    "themeDark": "#77f2f1",
    "themeDarker": "#99f5f4",
    "neutralLighterAlt": "#151717",
    "neutralLighter": "#1e2020",
    "neutralLight": "#2c302f",
    "neutralQuaternaryAlt": "#353939",
    "neutralQuaternary": "#3d4141",
    "neutralTertiaryAlt": "#5c6161",
    "neutralTertiary": "#c8c8c8",
    "neutralSecondary": "#d0d0d0",
    "neutralPrimaryAlt": "#dadada",
    "neutralPrimary": "#ffffff",
    "neutralDark": "#f4f4f4",
    "black": "#f8f8f8",
    "white": "#0c0d0c",
    "bodyBackground":"#2e2a2a"
}


export {lightCyan, darkCyan};
```

Comment: It would help a lot if you would provide a codepen or sandbox demo with the way you are using these themes, but from just looking what you have in here it's probably because you are mixing the `theme.palette` color slots with a `semanticColor` slot, which `bodyBackground` is. Also, not sure how you are using that changed slot? If you need the body background to be changed you need to apply that slot to the `body` styles.

Answer (score 0):

As you found, FluentUI does *not* alter the body background when you load a theme. You can fix this with one line of code, which you can add to the function where you load the theme:

```js
document.documentElement.style.background = paletteNext === "white" ? "black" : "white";
```

If you are interested in my method for toggling themes, see my answer to this other question: [Change theme like Fabric Web ( Default / Dark)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60214292/change-theme-like-fabric-web-default-dark/61890038#61890038)

Answer (score 0):

What works for me is setup correct ThemeProvider **to Body**:

```
<ThemeProvider
      theme={appTheme}
      applyTo="body"
    >
```

and in AppTheme set correct value for **semanticColors.bodyBackground**

```
...
export const appTheme: PartialTheme = {
  defaultFontStyle: { fontFamily: "Segoe UI", fontWeight: "regular" },
  fonts: {
    small: {
      fontSize: "10px",
    },
    ...
  },
  semanticColors: {
    bodyBackground: "#f5f7fa",
    ...
  },
  palette: {
    ....
```

full part of rendered object can meb

```
return (
    <ThemeProvider
      theme={appTheme}
      applyTo="body"
    >
      <Header />
      <Router>
        <Menu />
        <BreadCrumb />
        <TaskPaneMainRouterSwitch />
      </Router>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
```