# Change theme like Fabric Web ( Default / Dark)

Tags: office-ui-fabric

In the documentation page of fabric, now each example component have a change theme funcionality
ie: [example](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/controls/web/button)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GP9e2.png)

How can I achive this funcionality. I have 2 themes ([created in](https://aka.ms/themedesigner)) and I want to switch betwen thems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my preferred way, using React Context.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Fabric, Customizer } from '@fluentui/react';
import { useLocalStorage } from 'react-use';



// Setup Theme Context and create hooks

import {
  DefaultCustomizations,
  DarkCustomizations
} from '@uifabric/theme-samples';

export const ThemeList = {
  light: DefaultCustomizations,
  dark: DarkCustomizations
};

export const ThemeContext = React.createContext({
  theme: 'light',
  changeTheme: name => {}
});

const ThemeWrapper = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <ThemeContext.Consumer>
      {({ theme }) => (
        <Customizer {...ThemeList[theme]}>
          <Fabric>{children}</Fabric>
        </Customizer>
      )}
    </ThemeContext.Consumer>
  );
};

export const ThemeProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useLocalStorage('theme', 'dark');
  const changeTheme = name => ThemeList[name] && setTheme(name);
  const value = { theme, changeTheme };
  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={value}>
      <ThemeWrapper>{children}</ThemeWrapper>
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useTheme = () => React.useContext(ThemeContext);



// Now demo how to use it


export function App() {
  const { theme, changeTheme } = useTheme();

  return (
    <button onClick={() => changeTheme('dark')}>
      Switch to dark
    </button>
  );
}

import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
  <ThemeProvider>
    <App />
  </ThemeProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Note to moderator: Sorry that this answer was originally a duplicate. I deleted the duplicate.